# Change the textfield location of a JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, layout, jspinner

I'd like to custom a little bit the basic JSpinner of swing java API.
Basically, I want to move the textfield component initially located on the left of the arrow buttons. Instead, the texfield would be lcoated between the two arrows of the spinner, so that there's one arrow on top of the textfield and one arrow below the texfield.
But I don't know how to proceed...

Anyone would have an idea?

Comment: I did 2) and I will do 3). But, I really need to move the location of the textfield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to override the setLayout(LayoutManager) method of JSpinner to use a custom LayoutManager.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SpinnerLayoutTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    SpinnerNumberModel m = new SpinnerNumberModel(10, 0, 1000, 1);
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(m) {
      @Override public void setLayout(LayoutManager mgr) {
        super.setLayout(new SpinnerLayout());
      }
    };
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
    p.add(new JSpinner(m), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(spinner, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(16,16,16,16));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new SpinnerLayoutTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 160);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
class SpinnerLayout extends BorderLayout {
  @Override public void addLayoutComponent(Component comp, Object constraints) {
    if("Editor".equals(constraints)) {
      constraints = "Center";
    } else if("Next".equals(constraints)) {
      constraints = "North";
    } else if("Previous".equals(constraints)) {
      constraints = "South";
    }
    super.addLayoutComponent(comp, constraints);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make an `JPanel` and put a `JTextField` and the `JButtons` inside it. That's was soulution, when I had the same problem.

EDIT:

Arrowbuttons can you create with:

```
new javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicArrowButton(SwingConstants.NORTH);
```

Where SwingConstants.NORTH says that the arrow in the button is pointing upwards

Comment: Ok, but in this case you create from scrathc your own spinner widget. And you don't rely on the JSpinner existing one, isn't it? A drawback is that your own spinner, and especially your arrow buttons, don't have the same look that the "official" JSpinner and don't change accordingly with regards to the current LaF. Am I right?

Comment: You had to implement our own logic. It not as much work, as to change the UI of the JSpinner. It is possible to change the UI, but you had to code a lot of drawing logic, but then use the JSpinner logic. (BasicSpinnerUI.class) ..there is a private Handler class which is the LayoutManager of the Jspinner. This Componet mainly set up the look of the JSpinner.
Arrowbuttons can you create with (new javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicArrowButton(SwingConstants.NORTH);) where SwingConstants.NORTH says that the arrow in the button is pointing upwards.